# rest client in pentaho

Tags: rest, pentaho

I am very new to the pentaho data integration tool.

I want to consume a restful service(post web service) from my pentaho. For that i found that i should use a rest client. But when i give the url and body(as i want to consume post service) it is not making the necessary changes in the database.

Can anyone tell me how to give body in the rest client in pentaho? i suspect that there is some different way to give the body in the body field of rest client.

I am attaching the screenshot of the rest client which i am making.

Also can anyone suggest me some good links where i can find tutorials for pentaho.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PDI, you need to receive rows, and process them in the next step.

For this case, as stated in the [forum](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?83495-REST-Client-Step), you first need the "GENERATE ROWS" step, to make at least one call to the REST webservice.

Remember to generate only 1 row, else, you will make a X number of calls to the REST webservice.

Then, in the "REST CLIENT" step, choose the field that is generating the row with the URL in the attribute "Accept URL from field".

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use Generate Rows for your url then pass that to the REST Client and use the 'Accept URL from field'. That's the only I found it to work.