# Connect to QuickBase REST API with Pentaho data integration

Tags: rest, pentaho-data-integration, quickbase

Can anyone provide an example showing how to use the Pentaho REST transformation
to connect to the Quickbase API?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you connect to Quickbase API with any other tools like Postman, if you can then you have a simulation with Headers/Parameters, all you need to do is feed those to the REST API step.

Comment: It was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286586/rest-client-in-pentaho). Good luck.